# How to allow dragging to affect an element under another element

Tags: jquery, draggable

I'm making a map system similar to google maps with a mini map view in the top right. The problem is that sometimes it gets in the way I want to be able to drag the bottom bit even when I start the drag on the mini map. Is there a way to make this event pass throught the mini map div? thanks in advance!

[image: Mini map display]

EDIT:
Here is my code

```
        $('.Container').draggable({ 
              containment: "parent", 

              drag: function(event, ui) {   
                    var newLeft = (parseInt($('.Container').css('left'), 10)/-5)+80;
                    var newTop = (parseInt($('.Container').css('top'), 10)/-5)+80;                                              
                    $('.mini-viewport').css({'top': newTop, 'left': newLeft});                                      

            }

        });
```

And my html structure:

```
<div class="Viewport">

    <div class="mini-map">
        <div class="mini-viewport"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="Constrainer">    
        <div class="Container"></div>
    </div>  

</div>
```

Here is a JsFiddle of what I'm working with:
http://jsfiddle.net/thaiscorpion/XCCYe/

Comment: It is always a good idea to include your code in the question.

Comment: I don't know much about how .draggable works, but I assume you would want to have a mousedown function bound to the mini viewport that  starts the draggable function for container.

Comment: Either that, or maybe have the mini viewport fade out on hover, and fade back in when the mouse moves past it...this may be better anyway so the user has a better view of what they are dragging.

Answer (score 3):

Okey I've found a solution where I least expected it :D

if I add to the mini-map in css:

```
 pointer-events:none;
```

It makes all input pass through that element to any elements underneath, works great! Dont think IE Supports this tho I've still got to check so if anyone knows a cross browser way let me know.

Here is some information about pointer-events: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/CSS/pointer-events

Answer (score 0):

This may work...I have no way to test it though.

```
$('.mini-map').on('mousedown',  function (e){
     e.preventDefault();
    $('.container').mousedown();
});
```

You may also try this without the preventDefault...

```
$('.mini-map').on('mousedown',  function (){
     $('.container').mousedown();
});
```

Comment: VIDesignz thanks for your help but this doesnt work, it just makes no mouse events work on the mini map but doesnt let it pass through.

Comment: @Thaiscorpian Also, I had a typo in the script...my bad (Fixed it)

Comment: Added a fiddle to the qustion.